# Quickest way to remove many dynamic pages with duplicate content due to a spider trap

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, duplicate-content

I have an angular JS site that is reliant on google rendering the pages.

I created a spider trap and have about 9000 pages in the index which most are duplicate content.

Each page that is currently indexed has a self referencing canonical tag ('/duplicate_content_page_1' has a canonical of '/duplicate_content_page_1')

I want to remove these pages quickly so that I don’t get penalised for duplicate content, and so that the small amount of pages I actually want indexed don't get lumped in with the trash and don’t rank well.

These seem to be my options:

- Add meta no-index tag on each page that I want removed
- Disallow the pages in robots.txt
- Use googles remove URLs tool

From research it seems the best option is to add a no-index tag to the pages (also removing the canonical) and wait for the pages to be re crawled, but since the crawl rate is currently very low and that the presence of the no-index tag is reliant on google rendering each page I'm concerned this could take a long time, and that the longer this issue remains the more it will increase the risk of being penalised, and harm the ranking of the pages I want indexed - is there a faster approach?

I'm also planning to implement server side rendering which I'm hoping will increase the crawl rate since rendering won't be required

Comment: The "quickest way" is to remove the content and get the server to respond with a 410 for these URLs. How do you differentiate the pages you want to remove from the ones you want to keep? What webserver are you using?

Comment: thanks - I'm returning 410 for incorrect links and returning no-index for links that are correct but I don't want indexed - I'm using a IONOS VPS Windows server - the crawl rate is currently 50 crawls per day so is there a quicker way to remove these pages from the index?